# Why doesn't performSegue() call shouldPerformSegue()

Tags: swift, segue

Quite new to programming in Swift and mobile development in general. I am trying to use `performSegue()` and control it without if-else statements. I made a google search how to use `override func shouldPerformSegue()` and tried to implement it in different ways but none of them solved my situation. Here I need to segue to Yellow or Green views if the switch is on using corresponding buttons. Even if I made `return false`, the function does not cancel the segue to happen. What is the reason of this behaviour and how can I fix it? Many thanks.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var segueSwitch: UISwitch!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func yellowButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Yellow", sender: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func greenButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Green", sender: nil)
    }
    
    override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        // return segueSwitch.isOn
        return false
    }
    
}
```

[image: storyboard]

Comment: Have to taken steps to prove that `shouldPerformSegue` is called?  Print in there, or watch in debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shouldPerformSegue` does not get called if you use `performSegue(withIdentifier:` in code. This function only get called if the segue is triggered from storyboard.

You can easily test this by adding 2 Buttons to a ViewController in storyboard one with the storyboard segue and one with an `IBOutlet` to a new ViewController. Then add a `print` statement to `shouldPerformSegue`. In the Button outlet call `performSegue`. Only the first button performing the segue from storyboard will print to the console.

And additionally you don´t need it. Any validation you would perform in `shouldPerformSegue` can be done in the `...ButtonTapped` function:

```
@IBAction func yellowButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    if validateSegue(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Yellow", sender: nil)
    }
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    validateSegue()
}

func validateSegue() -> Bool{
    ......
}
```

Comment: Ah alright thanks a lot. There were some people saying ```shouldPerformSegue``` is called every time a ```performSegue``` runs. That's why I was confused. Now I got the point.
So in your code snippet ```shouldPerformSegue``` will only be called if there are any storyboard segues right?

Comment: @OğuzKaanAltun exactly right.

Answer (score 3):

This is deliberate and makes perfect sense. `shouldPerformSegue` lets you prevent an *automatically* triggered segue in case you don't want it performed. But if you didn't want a *manual* segue performed, all you had to do is *nothing* — don't say `performSegue` in the first place.

> and control it without if-else statements

If-else is exactly how to control it.